# Is the CocoaPod version of Material compatible with Swift 3

Tags: cosmicmind

I'm trying to use the CocoaPod version of Material with Swift 3.
However, when I open the project after installed Material 1.42.9 I cannot convert it to Swift 3 without making a lot of changes by my own.

Will their be a clean Swift 3 version in the near future?

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen in the github issue page, Swift 3 support is in the development branch.

https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/issues/516